# Powershell: Find a replace from a variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm new in Powershell, my code doesn't work, I can't figure out why despite spending hours trying..

What I would like to do:
1) Ask for user to type an IP Address
2) Find and replace a text by this IP Address

**My variables**

> $demande_server = Read-Host "IP Address" >> c:\temp\SQLtemp.txt
>
> $address = Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\SQLtemp.txt"

**Then**

> (Get-Content -path c:\temp\SQL.txt) | foreach {$_
>   -replace("NomServeur=","NomServeur="$address")} >> c:\temp\SQL.txt

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: there a lot of errors. Syntactically also and by logic also. You are not at all setting the content back actually. Doing input redirection wont help there.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me on the right direction !

Answer (score 1):

Try this logic:

```
$IPAddress=Read-Host "Enter the IP Address: "
$file_Content= Get-Content "c:\temp\SQLtemp.txt"
foreach($file in $file_Content)
{
$file.replace("NomServeur=","NomServeur=$IPAddress") >> c:\temp\new_OUTPUT.txt
}
```

So, "new_OUTPUT.txt" will have the new output which should have the replaced text.

Note: If you want to set it back to the old file. Then store the entire result in a variable and then overwrite the old file with the entire result set.

Hope it helps.

**Sample OUTPUT:**

This is my file content:

[image: File_Content]

This is the Replaced File Content:

[image: Replaced Content]

My Input was *192.168.1.1*